# How do I get DRAM address instead of Virtual address

Tags: c

I understand if I try to print the address of an element of an array it would be an address from virtual memory not from real memory (physical memory) i.e DRAM.

```
printf ("Address of A[5] and A[6] are %u and %u", &A[5], &A[6]);
```

I found addresses were consecutive (assuming elements are chars). In reality they may not be consecutive at least not in the DRAM. I want to know the real addresses. How do I get that?

I need to know this for either Windows or Linux.

Comment: It depends what platform (i.e. OS) you're on.  Note also that virtual addresses may not necessarily be mapped to physical addresses.

Comment: `I want to know that real address.` : no you don't!!  What is the actual problem you think you are going to solve by having a physical address instead of a virtual?

Comment: Two consecutive entries in an array are almost certainly going to have consecutive addresses, even in physical memory.

Comment: @CarlNorum this is just an example. I real case I might have 50 chars, and I guess, in physical memory it may not be consecutive.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Though if the array is more than a page in size, then all bets are off, right?

Comment: @user25108: p2v mapping can only go to 1 page (typically 4KB) granularity. 50 bytes are most certainly consecutive

Comment: @mvp, even if they are consecutive , the address are certainly different from VM. How do I get that real address?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Even if the array is more than a page, the odds are much more than 99% that two consecutive characters in virtual memory are also consecutive in physical memory.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the physical address for a virtual address from user code; only the lowest levels of the kernel deal with physical addresses, and you'd have to intercept things there.

Note that the physical address for a virtual address may not be constant while the program runs — the page might be paged out from one physical address and paged back in to a different physical address.  And if you make a system call, this remapping could happen between the time when the kernel identifies the physical address and when the function call completes because the program requesting the information was unscheduled and partially paged out and then paged in again.

Comment: You don't even have to make a system call. It is enough to access an unmapped page. On the other hand, depending on process privileges and system configuration, you might be able to use `mlock(2)` to force the page(s) to be memory-resident, in which case their physical mapping will be stable. Even if you do that, I don't believe there is a way to find out what the mapping is, except in the kernel.

Comment: @rici Access to an unmapped page goes nowhere, hence the terminology. It is true that many OSes provide some way to write user-mode drivers with hardcoded addresses, though.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: s/unmapped/swapped-out/. I shouldn't comment when I'm tired.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that, in general, for user processes or threads in a multiprocessing OS such as Windows or Linux, it is not possible to find the address even of of a static variable in the processor's memory address space, let alone the DRAM address.

There are a number of reasons for this:

1. The memory allocated to a process is virtual memory. The OS can remap this process memory from time-to-time from one physical address range to another, and there is no way to detect this remaping in the user process. That is, the physical address of a variable can change during the lifetime of a process.
2. There is no interface from userspace to kernel space that would allow a userspace process to walk through the kernel's process table and page cache in order to find the physical address of the process. In Linux you can write a kernel module or driver that can do this.
3. The DRAM is often mapped to the procesor address space through a memory management unit (MMU) and memory cache. Although the MMU maping of DRAM to the processor address space is usually done only once, during system boot, the processor's use of the cache can mean that values written to a variable might not be written through to the DRAM in all cases.

There are OS-specific ways to "pin" a block of allocated memory to a static physical location. This is often done by device drivers that use DMA. However, this requires a level of privilege not available to userspace processes, and, even if you have the physical address of such a block, there is no pragma or directive in the commonly used linkers that you could use to allocate the BSS for a process at such a physical address.

Even *inside* the Linux kernel, virtual to physical address translation is not possible in the general case, and requires knowledge about the means that were used to allocate the memory to which a particular virtual address refers.

Here is a link to an article called *[Translating Virtual to Physical Address on Windows: Physical Addresses](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/translating-virtual-to-physical-address-on-windows-physical-addresses/)* that gives you a hint as to the extreme ends to which you must go to get physical addresses on Windows.